# Prove $\int_0^1 | \Sigma_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k \theta}|d \theta \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $a_1,...a_N$ are complex numbers with $|a_i|=1$ for $i=1,....N$. Prove that:

$\int_0^1 | \Sigma_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k \theta}|d \theta \geq 1$

My attempt:

I know that $\int_0^1 e^{2 \pi i k \theta} d \theta = 1$ if $k=0$ and equals $0$ if $k \neq 0$ otherwise.

I'm trying to use the fact that if $f \in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$ then $f \in L^2$ and $||f||_2^2 \leq ||f||_1||f||_{\infty}$

I'm stuck in tunnel vision.. Could use a new perspective!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can also show this by the triangle inequality for integrals. First, I claim that

$$  | \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k \theta}|=| \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i (k-1) \theta}|\cdot \vert e^{2\pi i\theta} \vert= | \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i (k-1) \theta}| .$$

Thus our integral equals

$$ \int_0^1 | \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i(k-1)\theta}|d \theta \geq \Big\vert \int_0^1  \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i (k-1) \theta}d \theta \Big\vert =|a_1|=1. $$

I'm not completely sure about this argument, since it seems to work whenever one of the $a_i$-s have absolute value one.

Comment: Good argument, +1. I edited it to shorten it, because it's very simple. Your last line: There is no problem; all we need is that $|a_1|=1$

Comment: Okay, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is pretty good. Note that

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \left|\sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k\theta} \right|^2\textrm{d}\theta &=\int_0^1   \left(\sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k\theta}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^N \overline{a_j} e^{-2\pi i j\theta}\right)\textrm{d}\theta\\
&= \sum_{j,k=1}^N \int_0^1 a_k \overline{a_j} e^{i(k-j)\theta}\textrm{d}\theta \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|^2=N
\end{align}
By your observation. Furthermore, by your inequality, we have

$$
N=\int_0^1 \left|\sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k\theta} \right|^2\textrm{d}\theta \leq \left\| \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k\theta} \right\|_{\infty} \int_0^1 \left|\sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k\theta} \right|\textrm{d}\theta 
$$

Since $\left\| \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{2\pi i k\theta} \right\|_{\infty}\leq \sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|=N,$ you get your result.